# Between assembly versions, how do I check what types are available to me?

Tags: c#

If I have an assembly `Foo.dll` and I add it as a reference to my project, with `SpecificVersion = false`, how do I check at runtime what types are available to me?

Let's say there are two Interfaces, `IAbc1` and `IAbc2`, the latter having been added in a later revision I am currently compiling against. How do I check, at runtime, whether `IAbc2` is available to me?

Comment: Note that "Specific version" applies only to search during compilation, it will not be in any way present in resulting exe. What matters is version of DLL that will be loaded at runtime - it looks like you are doing some additional steps to replace DLL later to get older version...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, ideally I'd never face an old assembly again, but that's not the reality I live in :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
   foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
        //do something with type
    }
```

where `assembly` is an [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) type you are investigating.
So, for example, if you have a dll, you can construct that [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyPath);
```

Comment: If I see correctly, `Assembly.Load()` requires version information. If I had that in the first place, it would render further efforts moot. Also, I suspect the respective assembly should already be loaded (I added the reference to the project), or am I wrong in that regard?

Comment: If the assembly is already loaded you can use [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) to find a list of all referencies, filter out that one you are interested in, and investirgate over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can even use linq to make it shorter:

```
Assembly assemly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Mypath");
bool exist = assemly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "myinterface") != null;
```